# Moving a folder from TFS 2008 to TFS 2010 (with history)

Tags: tfs, tfs-migration, tfs-to-tfs-migration-tool

I need to migrate/sync(one way) a single folder from TFS 2008 to TFS 2010 with history intact.
I am not able to migrate all the content from TFS 2008 as it's used by multiple teams. 
I am looking for step by step guidance on how to do that. 
Thanks

Comment: Why not move to TFS2010 and use from VS2005/2008/2010 (for the former two you need the forward compatibility updates)? ("Used by multiple updates" just requires telling people to install updates --- this can be done ahead of the TFS import.)

Comment: We cannot just "move" to TFS2010 (the reason is mentioned in the question). The requirement is to move stuff gradually. TFS2008 server will be running in parallel with new TFS2010

Comment: I was looking for expansion of the reason because "used by multiple teams" seems a marginal (at best) reason to me as 2010 is backward compatible (with the patch).

Comment: I don't really want to expand on that. I am not looking for any other alternative solutions. I just need to know if it's possible to do, what is described in my question and how. Simples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/177800/how-to-transfer-from-scrum-for-team-system-v2-to-visual-studio-scrum-v1

Just had to select different template in step 4.